# get co-ordinates from firebase to draw a polyline

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the co-ordinates in firebase and draw polyline to show it on map. Currently, nothing is shown on the map.

Here is my data structure:

```
history
 |- MXDFHE8877334 ------random run id
     |- co-ordinates
        |-0
        |   |-- latitude:-3.44444
        |   |-- longitude:-54.434343
        |-1
        |   |-- latitude:-4.0444
        |   |-- longitude:-24.434343
        |-2
        |   |-- latitude:-5.455459
        |   |-- longitude:-476.434343
     |- distance:2323
     |- timestamp:23233439
 |- MX24343643232 ------random run id
     |- co-ordinates
        |-0
        |   |-- latitude:-3.44444
        |   |-- longitude:-54.434343
        |-1
        |   |-- latitude:-4.0444
        |   |-- longitude:-24.434343
        |-2
        |   |-- latitude:-5.455459
        |   |-- longitude:-476.434343
        |-3
        |   |-- latitude:-3.74343
        |   |-- longitude:-76.434343
     |- distance:1234
     |- timestamp:9873489
```

Here is my drawPolyline()function:

```
    private void drawPolyline(){
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("history").child(runId).child("co-ordinates");
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                polylineOptions.color(Color.RED);
                polylineOptions.width(3);
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("co-ordinates").getChildren()) {
                    double latitude = ds.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    double longitude = ds.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    polylineOptions.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
                }
                Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        };
        uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
    }
```

I am not sure how to fix it so then it gets all the latitude and longitude from the points(0,1,2,3,4,5...)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems like `uidRef` puts you at `co-ordinates` but in your `onDataChange` you then look for a `co-ordinates` child.  Just remove the `.child("co-ordinates")` part in the `DataSnapshot` loop..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there ... `uidRef` reference is already at "co-ordinates" so remove that de-reference in the `onDataChange` loop.

```
for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
```